# Ngrx redirect after http request failed

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a ngrx effect for load data from service http
and I want redirect to url in case of error while the data is loaded.
The problem is the redirect is not working and the page is blank and there
is no code in the result page.

This is effect for load data from service:

```
loadConfig$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AppActionTypes.loadConfig),

      switchMap(() => {
        return this.configService.getConfig().pipe(
          map((config: any) => {
            console.log('loadConfig  %o', config);
            return AppActionTypes.configLoaded({configuration: config});
          }),
          catchError((err, caught) => {
            console.log('loadConfig catchErr %o', err);
            return of(AppActionTypes.errorAppInitializer(err));
          })
        );
      })
    );
  });
```

And this effect is for handled error:

```
errorAppInitializerRedirect$ = createEffect(() => {
      return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AppActionTypes.errorAppInitializer),
        tap(() => {
          console.log('errorAppInitializerRedirect');
          return this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/errors');
        })
      );
    } ,
    {dispatch: false}
  );
```

And in the browser shows the page blank without any html rendered.

```
  <app-root></app-root>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The snippet seems ok to me. Make sure that both effects are registered and that the console logs are logged. Also verify the auth/errors route.

Answer (score 0):

1- Remove `return` from `Tap` operator in `errorAppInitializerRedirect$`:

```
errorAppInitializerRedirect$ = createEffect(() => {
      return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AppActionTypes.errorAppInitializer),
        tap(() => {
          console.log('errorAppInitializerRedirect');
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/errors');
        })
      );
    } ,
    {dispatch: false}
  );
```

`Tap` operator can't returning something different than the original. In the [RxJs document](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) they describe `Tap` as "A function that returns an Observable identical to the source"... "Used when you want to affect outside state with a notification **without altering** the notification"

2- Check if you really have the right reference `this` when you call `this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/errors')` because it's a different scope inside the effect.

I can develop the answer according to your feedback.